# Swift 3 checking current URL on WebView

Tags: swift, parsing, url, web, swift3

I have my webView login page with many links on it, but i need only "Log in" link to be clickable

How do i check current URL String in the following method?

```
 func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool{

 print("Url has changed")
    let finish = "**link one**"


            if **Current URL* == finish {
                print("Url has changed to main")
                print("**link one**")
                return true

}
    return false


    }
```

Comment: Add `UIWebViewDelegate` to controller and in `viewDidLoad` add `webView.delgate = self`. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate

Comment: Note that `WebView` (macOS) and `UIWebView` (iOS) are different classes with different interfaces.